# Definition of ergodicity and ergodicity for second moments of a stochastic process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, ergodic-theory, time-series

According to this [topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3117771/definition-of-ergodicity-and-ergodic-process), we understand well the relation between the ergodicity for dynamical system and the **mean ergodicity** of a stochastic process. More exactly, we have the Ergodic Theorem (See page 413 of [A. N. Shiryaev](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-2539-1))
[image]

The following definition is about a random process $(Y_t)_{t \in \mathbb Z}$

[image]

where $\gamma_j := E(Y_t - \mu)(Y_{t-j} - \mu)$, with $\mu=E Y_t$.

But now where does it come in or how do these ergodic concepts of dynamical systems relate to the concept of ergodicity for the second moments?